# How to extract numbers inidvidually on a date then storing it into an array - C Language

Tags: c

I need to extract EACH number then storing it into an array in ascending order.

Im stuck in this part

```
int mm,dd,yy;

printf("Date (MM/DD/YYYY): ");
scanf("%d/%d/%d", &mm, &dd, &yy);

printf("Date: %02d/%02d/%d", mm, dd, yy);
```

**The Output should be like this:**

Date: 06/12/1999

Sorted array: 0 1 1 2 6 9 9 9

Comment: You probably don't want to read these as integers, as the `0` you want from`06` won't be there (because `06` will be simply `6`)

Comment: Why do you expect your program to print `Sorted array: 0 1 1 2 6 9 9 9`? I don't see any attempt of your program to print such a line.

Comment: This code has shown no attempt to sort the digits.  mang, post what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

It should be done easily by reading the input as string and extracting digits.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) {
    char input[128];
    int numberCount = 0;
    int numbers[128];
    int i;

    printf("Date: ");
    if (scanf("%127s", input) != 1) return 1;
    for (i = 0; input[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (isdigit((unsigned char)input[i])) {
            numbers[numberCount++] = input[i] - '0';
        }
    }

    printf("Date: %s\n", input);

    printf("Numbers:");
    for (i = 0; i < numberCount; i++) {
        printf(" %d", numbers[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Check `man (3) getc`. There is `int getchar(void)`. It lets you read the next character.
K&R illustrate the use on several occasions in the beginning their book